# Are the Hadoop {start|stop}-all.sh scripts typically used w/ cloudera 3 clusters, and if so, how?

Tags: installation, hadoop

I've got a cluster I'm setting up Cloudera 3 on, and it is unclear on whether I should be using these start/stop scripts like I used to with the standard Apache Hadoop setup (where I had a specific user account that ran all the Hadoop stuff).  With CDH3, I got these services running as root.

What is the suggested secure and convenient way to issue global starts and stops with Cloudera 3?  Do users who want to use these scripts setup keys so root can login to the other boxes?  If so, how is this setup by a sudo'd user (just `sudo su` and setup keys?)?

Also, when I tried to run `sudo /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/bin/start-all.sh` (with no keys setup for the root user to connect to the remove boxes), I get the following output:

```
starting namenode, logging to /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/bin/../logs/hadoop-root-namenode-meez01.out
May not run daemons as root. Please specify HADOOP_NAMENODE_USER
<asks me for root@myserver's password>
....
<similar message for jobtracker>
```

**update:** I know *someone* out there has to be using Cloudera.. is this a conspiracy to get me to pay for their support?!  j/k. if anything, let mek now how you are using it

Comment: I got a tumble-weed badge for this bad girl.. who dares answer my question! please dare

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for similar info, and found it here:

http://www.migrate2cloud.com/blog/hadoop-cluster-with-hadoop-0-20-and-ubuntu-10-04

You can start/stop using the /etc/init.d/hadoop* scripts

Comment: I didn't see anything about starting/stopping the slave nodes from one server, which is what I'm looking for.  Currently I can already use the etc/init.d scripts to start/stop locally.  Let me know if I missed something please